# Error: Wrong architecture 'amd64' & Unable to locate package libc6-dev-i386 [Install libc6-dev-i386]

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I'm trying to install the [Redox-OS](http://www.redox-os.org/) files via `curl -sf https://raw.githubusercontent.com/redox-os/redox/master/bootstrap.sh -o bootstrap.sh && bash -e bootstrap.sh` (as referenced in the [Book](https://doc.redox-os.org/book/getting_started/preparing_the_build.html)) and I get the `Unable to locate package libc6-dev-i386`.

When installing the `libc6-dev-i386` via [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libc6-dev-i386/download) and using the GUI package installer, I receive `Error: Wrong architecture 'amd64'`. Using `dpkg` and `apt-get` I also receive `Unable to locate package...`. I've tried using `dpkg --force-all` as referenced in a few Stack Overflow articles, but to no avail.

I am running `LXLE Linux 14.04.4 32-bit`.

How can I install `libc6-dev-i386`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "wrong architecture 'amd64'" error is because you tried to install a 64-bit ("amd64") package on a 32-bit ("i386") system.  The `libc6-dev-i386` package is sort of a strange one because it's built only for 64-bit systems, but it actually contains 32-bit software.  It's meant to help with compiling 32-bit programs on 64-bit systems.

Since you're running a 32-bit system, `libc6-dev` is the package you need.  That contains the necessary headers and libraries for compiling 32-bit programs.  (On a 64-bit system, `libc6-dev` provides files for compiling 64-bit programs, which is why there's also a `libc6-dev-i386` package with the 32-bit files.)

Your `bootstrap.sh` script has the name `libc6-dev-i386` hard-coded in it, which means the script assumes it's being run on a 64-bit system.  The simplest thing to do is probably to just edit the script and change `libc6-dev-i386` to `libc6-dev`, then run it again.

Comment: I inspected the script and indeed saw the hardcoded `libc6-dev-i386` in it. I'm interested to know why seemingly there is an assumption that the PC is 64-bit? Maybe there isn't and I'll have to look further into it and see what else I can learn from it. All-in-all, thanks for a swift, detailed answer. Answer accepted